# Trouble with leaflet maps (GET mapbox tiles unauthorized 401)

Tags: leaflet, mapbox

I am trying to add leaflet maps to my webpage and I am using Mapbox tiles. I am not able to get the map in the basic tutorial to work, all I am seeing is a grey screen. I have a mp id from mapbox and I have added it to my code. Attaching relevant code below.

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/rakshak.l937n12c/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
```

and this is what I am seeing in the console:

```
GET http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/rakshak.l937n12c/13/4093/2723.png 401 (Unauthorized)
```

In the css I have just put the map height to height: 100vh.

All I am seeing on my screen are the map zoom controllers and a grey screen. Am I missing an important step ?

Edit 1: Update JS code:

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
L.tileLayer('http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/rakshak.l937n12c/{z}/{x}/{y}.{format}?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoicmFrc2hhayIsImEiOiJ5cHhqeHlRIn0.Vi87VjI1cKbl1lhOn95Lpw', {
attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: A token is requested : see https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/. Your request should look like : `http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapid}/{z}/{x}/{y}.{format}?access_token=<your access token>`. You have only set `mapid`

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I added the access token from the mopbox screen and I am still seeing a grey screen and the same error message in the console. I have added my update js code to my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set up your tileLayer to include your map's id and your user token:

```
var tileLayer = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{mapId}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token={token}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://mapbox.com">Mapbox</a>',
    subdomains: ['a','b','c','d'],
    mapId: <YOUR MAPID HERE>,
    token: <YOUR TOKEN HERE>
});
```

Here's a working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Kf3f8h?p=preview

Comment: Tried this, now I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in line leaflet.js:7.

Comment: Well, that code i gave you, works, you can check the example. What can i say? Here's another Plunker using your MapID and Token: http://plnkr.co/edit/kzA9Vw?p=preview, it works. What you are doing wrong i can't see based on the code you provided. Could you share a Plunker or JSfiddle that has your problem?

Comment: Never used plnkr before so not sure if I did it right. Here is the link: http://plnkr.co/edit/9TLUXY9zutATHHBdCdMk?p=preview

Comment: Your CSS is wrong you've got to give the html and body element a height of 100% too: `html, body, #map { height: 100%; }` and you forgot to initialize the map so when you use `tileLayer.addTo(map)` it can't add it to `map` because there is no `map` thus it fails with the error you mentioned. Here's your updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/FuX4NTdHkzFBp7UYg94V?p=preview